# Issues with Selecting Date Ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to return results between 01/01/2019 and 08/13/2019. I am having trouble with the date ranges.

First I tried the SQL below using the commented out piece and I received all dates.  Then I tried using the # method that I have below and I am receiving the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near '#'

I think there might be an issue with how the dates are formatted in the db (which I have no control over) but I tried using

```
Format(b.QualifyingEventDate, "yyyymmdd")
```

but that didn't work.

I've been working on this all afternoon ad it seems like it should be a simple query. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
SELECT 
    a.GroupID,
    c.employername,
    b.QualifyingEventDate, b.QualifyingEventType
FROM 
    MST_MEMBER_DEMOGRAPHICS AS a 
JOIN
    DET_ENROLLMENT_DETAILS AS b ON a.BFUNIQUEID = b.BFUNIQUEID
JOIN
    MST_EMPLOYER_GROUP_MASTER AS c ON a.groupid = c.groupid
WHERE 
    a.GroupID = TestClient
    AND QualifyingEventType <> 'NULL'
    --and QualifyingEventDate between '01/01/2019' and '08/13/2019' 
    AND QualifyingEventDate > #01/01/2019#
    AND QualifyingEventDate < #08/13/2019# 
ORDER BY 
    b.QualifyingEventDate, a.groupid, b.QualifyingEventType
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: To save time and confusion in future, please post the table definition. This is the first database I've ever seen where a NULL is represented by the string 'NULL'

Answer (score 3):

The `WHERE` clause, assuming you want inclusive, should be this:

```
WHERE a.GroupID = TestClient
  and QualifyingEventType IS NOT NULL -- notice 'IS NOT' instead of '<>'
  and QualifyingEventDate between '2019-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-08-13 23:59:59'
```

This is assuming that `QualifyingEventDate` is a datetime data type.  Not including the time component could potentially cause some casting issues with `date`.

Comment: The `#` delimiter for dates is used in MS-Access, but not in Transact-SQL (SQL Server) or any other DBMS I've used. Michael also uses the ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD which is unambiguous and will work whether your server is configured for US style dates or those used everywhere else. Final comment is that if `BETWEEN` doesn't work for you because you don't want to include either the start date or the end date, I've found it helpful to use `'2019-01-01' <= QualifyingEventDate AND QualifyingEventDate < '2019-08-13'` for instance (i.e. exclude the 13th of August) for clarity (IMHO at least).

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  Michael's suggestion did not return any results.  I have run queries on this DB before and I know that <> 'NULL' works when trying to exclude the NULL values.  In this DB they aren;t actually NULL, they are the value 'NULL'. The issue is with the dates.  As mentioned Michael's suggestion did not return results the below code returns results that go back to the year 2015

WHERE a.GroupID = 'HORACE'
  and QualifyingEventType <> 'NULL'
  and QualifyingEventDate >= '01/01/2019 00.00.00.000000000' 
  and QualifyingEventDate < '08/14/2019 00.00.00.000000000'

Comment: What data type is QualifyingEventDate?  From what you are saying, it almost sounds like the type might be a varchar that is storing a date format, in which case between '2018-01-01' and '2018-10-01' or whatever would be doing a STRING comparison instead of a date comparison.  In the comment above, ">= '01/01/2019' and <= '08/14/2019' would get everything that alphabetically is between those, which will be 01-08 of all of the years.

Comment: Continuing on the comment above, if the field is a varchar storing a datetime type format, you could do something like "and cast(QualifyingEventDate as datetime) between ....", but then if there is any indexing on that column you will lose that and potentially have a much more expensive query.